# Cannot start ipython notebook

Tags: python-2.7, macports, jupyter-notebook

I have installed py27 and ipython and notebook by macport on my mac osx10.9.4.

I can open ipython and it works fine but I cannot open ipython notebook.

After I type in

```
ipython notebook
```

I got this.

> 2014-07-23 12:22:11.626 [NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir:
>   u'/Users/zhiyiwu/.ipython/profile_default' 2014-07-23 12:22:11.630
>   [NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN:
>   http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "/opt/local/bin/ipython", line 5, in
>   
>       start_ipython()   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/**init**.py",
>   line 120, in start_ipython
>       return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 563, in launch_instance
>       app.initialize(argv)   File "", line 2, in initialize   File
>   "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 92, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py",
>   line 321, in initialize
>       super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)   File "", line 2, in initialize   File
>   "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 92, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py",
>   line 381, in initialize
>       self.parse_command_line(argv)   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py",
>   line 316, in parse_command_line
>       return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)   File "", line 2, in parse_command_line   File
>   "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 92, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 475, in parse_command_line
>       return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)   File "", line 2, in initialize_subcommand   File
>   "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 92, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 413, in initialize_subcommand
>       self.subapp.initialize(argv)   File "", line 2, in initialize   File
>   "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 92, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py",
>   line 745, in initialize
>       self.init_webapp()   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py",
>   line 632, in init_webapp
>       self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py",
>   line 125, in listen
>       sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py",
>   line 98, in bind_sockets
>       0, flags)): gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
>
> If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
>       https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org
>
> You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use
>   "%debug" to interactively debug it.
>
> Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled
>   via:
>       c.Application.verbose_crash=True

Is there anyway to get my notebook started?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be related to ipython ip socket issues. A verified workaround:

```
ipython notebook --ip=127.0.0.1
```

is presented at https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6191#issuecomment-49903748.

Answer (score 0):

I take another distribution of python, it's Anaconda. You can find here : https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/
It contains an IDE with Ipython terminal, it's very usefull and you can have easily access to the notebook to.