# Cannot start ipython notebook by missing a module called zmq.eventloop

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I have installed **ipython Notebook** lately for my machine learning course following the instructions below:

**Step 1: Create and activate a new virtual environment (recommended)**

```
# Create a virtual environment named e.g. dato-env
virtualenv dato-env

# Activate the virtual environment
source dato-env/bin/activate
```

**Step 2: Ensure pip version >= 7**

```
# Make sure pip is up to date
pip install --upgrade pip
```

**Step 3: Ensure installation of IPython and IPython Notebook**

```
# Install IPython Notebook (optional)
pip install "ipython[notebook]"
```

Everything worked just fine till I have started **ipython notebook** server by typing the following command:

```
ipython notebook
```

Then the following error popped up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(start_ipython())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 118, in start_ipython
return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 591, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
File "<decorator-gen-111>", line 2, in initialize
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 305, in initialize
super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 386, in initialize
self.parse_command_line(argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 300, in parse_command_line
return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
File "<decorator-gen-4>", line 2, in parse_command_line
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 487, in parse_command_line
return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 418, in initialize_subcommand
subapp = import_item(subapp)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython_genutils/importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 32, in <module>
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
ImportError: No module named zmq.eventloop
```

I have tried some of methods in the past Stackoverflow posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815673/cant-install-pyzmp-for-python-dependencies) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910583/cannot-start-ipython-notebook). But seems they did not resolve my problem. I will much appreciate if anybody can help me with some workarounds and explain what're actually the issues. Thank you in advance

Best Regards,

Comment: `I have installed ipython Notebook` - you may consider being more specific here.

Comment: @cel: Hi, cel. I have just updated my question. Hope it's clear. Thank you

Comment: After activating the virtualenv, does `python -m IPython notebook` work for you?

Comment: Hi,cel. I still did not work. Here's what I've got with python -m IPython notebook: /home/livetolove128/dato-env/bin/python: No module named IPython

Comment: Did you activate your virtualenv before executing it?

Comment: Hi, cel. I did activate virtualenv and a virtual environment. Seems it did not help.

Comment: Hi, cel. your solution did actually work. Thank you so much. May you put it as an official answer to let me accept it. Again, thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

I have resolved the same error on  my system using this command:
sudo apt-get install python-zmq